# Basic comparison statement in javascript

Tags: javascript, firebase

So I'm trying to run a comparison statement with the firebase SDK.

I've got a function which checks if the phone number or email has a valid invite value / document exists within the database.

I want to add a comparison that says if the invitationData is valid and the claimedDate value is not equal to the data type null or the invitationData is valid and the string value is not equal to null then alert invitation not confirmed. The problem I'm having is with the || or operator I can only seem to get this comparison to work if I'm just doing one argument when I add the or it stops working.

```
    async function checkInvitation(email = '', phone = '') {
    try {
    let snapshot = firebase.firestore().collection(COLLECTIONS.INVITATIONS);
    if (email) {
      snapshot = snapshot.where('email', '==', email);
    } else if (phone) {
      snapshot = snapshot.where('phone', '==', phone);
    }

    let invitationData = await snapshot.get();
    if (!invitationData || invitationData.docs.length === 0) {
      Alert.alert(
        'Invitation not confirmed',
        'Please try again or join our waiting list.',
      );
      return false;
    }
    if ((invitationData && invitationData.docs[0].data().claimedDate !== null) || (invitationData && invitationData.docs[0].data().claimedDate != "somestring")) {
      Alert.alert(
        'Invitation not confirmed',
        'This invitation has already been used',
      );
      return false;
    }
    return invitationData.docs[0].id;
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
    throw new Error(error);
  }
}
```

Comment: You have `x !== a || x !== b`, where a is different from b. That won't work because any value x will fulfill this test. You need `x !== a && x !== b` do this: `const claimedDate = invitationData?.docs[0].data().claimedDate;` then `if (claimedDate && claimedDate !== "somestring")`

Answer (score 1):

If you shorten it (excuse the pseudo nature) it looks as follows :

```
if (claimedDate !== null || claimedDate != "somestring")
```

I'm pretty sure that's not what you are meaning. Perhaps you are intending an AND?

Comment: It's just this line I'm having problems with the rest is working

    if ((invitationData && invitationData.docs[0].data().claimedDate !== null) || (invitationData && invitationData.docs[0].data().claimedDate != "somestring")) {

It needs to check if the invitationData is valid AND check if the claimedDate is !== null OR != "somestring"

So invitationData needs to be met AND then not equal to one of the other values.

Comment: exactly.  claimedDate!=null AND claimedDate != 'somestring'.  as you have it it will ALWAYS resolve to true - if you think about it

Comment: Its meant to say 

if ( ( invitation is valid and claimed date is not equal to null) OR (invitation is valid and claimed date is not equal to 'somestring') 

so when the value is not equal to either of those conditions and the invite is valid. Alert the user that the This invitation has already been used.

Comment: I just rewrote it like this and still no luck

if ( (invitationData && invitationData.docs[0].data().claimedDate != null) || (invitationData && invitationData.docs[0].data().claimedDate != 'somestring') )